# Highcharts dynamic data fetching in React

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, axios

I am trying to use `highcharts` module (highstock single line series) with React. I tried fetching the data from URL using `axios` but data is not displaying in the graph.

Here is the snippet of my function for data passing:

```
series: [
    { name: 'Counts',
      data: (function() {
              axios.get('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-c.json')
              .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data, 'data fetched');
                return res.data;
              })
              .catch(err => {
                return err;
              })
          }()),
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
    }
    }
  ],
```

I also tried fetching data in component life cycle method '`componentDidMount`' but was unable to get the result out of method and pass it tot the data key of the series. Help Appreciated.

Comment: Hi @bubble-cord, Your problem has been resolved or do you still need help?

Comment: @ppotaczek It's been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems here, first you need to return something from your IIFE:

```
(function() {
  return axios.get('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-c.json') // you're missing return here
   .then(res => {
     console.log(res.data, 'data fetched');
     return res.data;
   })
   .catch(err => {
     return err;
   })
 }())
```

But if you try to assign this IIFE to a variable, you'll see it returns a promise which is still not what you need, you need the resolved value from the promise.

What I suggest is using `async/await` in your `componentDidMount` and `setState` with the fetched data. Like this:

in your state:

```
this.state = {
  data: [],
}
```

in `componentDidMount`:

```
async componentDidMount(){
  let data = await axios.get('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-c.json')
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => {
      return err;
  })
  this.setState({data})
}
```

This way you will set the data in `state` to the response from the call
and in your render you can use

```
series: [
    { name: 'Counts',
      data: this.state.data,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: @bubble-cord Happy it worked, feel free to mark it as answered.

Comment: Is there any particular format of the API that need to be used for data fetching? I tried changing my api and then again the graph goes blank, but the data only shows in console.

Comment: how do you display the data? Can you set up a https://codesandbox.io/s/y2lrywpk21

Comment: I think it's because of the format you're receiving the data, it's an array with arrays. Highcharts expects an array with numbers: `[1,2,3,3,4]`; you're sending `[[1554901500, 2], [1554901620, 5], [1554901740, 9]....]`. Modify the data on the frontend of backend and it's going to work.

Comment: I am sending the values for [x,y] coordinates in the form [[1554901500, 2], [1554901620, 5], [1554901740, 9]....], where first one denotes epoch time and second no of data associated at that time.

Comment: I don't think highcharts accept this format, you have to check the library's documentation. https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/ check how every part of series has an array of data, but it's a one dimensional array.

Comment: So it's an issue related to back-end, front-end is receiving data properly?

Comment: You can change the data in the front-end.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code for on how to change the data in the front end?